# Failed IBM DSX Desktop installation

Tags: data-science-experience, dsx-desktop

I'm trying to install IBM DSX Desktop, but after the application window is shown, the program shows spinning circles endlessly. Looking in the log, the application seems to be stuck in an endless update loop checking for app updates forever. Latest Docker is installed and running. Hyper-V enabled...

```
[2018-02-15 15:30:59:0158] [info] Checking for app updates...
[2018-02-15 15:30:59:0165] [info] Update for win32-x64-prod-v1.2.0 is not available
[2018-02-15 15:30:59:0169] [info] Checking for image updates...
[2018-02-15 15:30:59:0177] [info] Update for win32-x64-prod-v1.2.0 is not available
[2018-02-15 15:30:59:0183] [info] controller: emit update-not-available
[2018-02-15 15:30:59:0183] [info] controller: emit update-not-available
[2018-02-15 15:30:59:0201] [info] Update for win32-x64-prod-v1.2.0 is not available
[2018-02-15 15:30:59:0205] [info] Getting update information from updates.json
[2018-02-15 15:30:59:0209] [info] dsxJSON is [object Object]
[2018-02-15 15:30:59:0209] [info] DSX updates not available...
[2018-02-15 15:30:59:0209] [info] util: emit update-not-available for image
[2018-02-15 15:30:59:0209] [info] controller: emit update-not-available
[2018-02-15 15:30:59:0210] [info] controller: emit update-not-available
[2018-02-15 15:30:59:0213] [info] Getting update information from updates.json
[2018-02-15 15:30:59:0223] [info] dsxJSON is [object Object]
[2018-02-15 15:30:59:0224] [info] DSX updates not available...
[2018-02-15 15:30:59:0224] [info] util: emit update-not-available for image
[2018-02-15 15:30:59:0224] [info] controller: emit update-not-available
[2018-02-15 15:30:59:0225] [info] Getting update information from updates.json
[2018-02-15 15:30:59:0226] [info] dsxJSON is [object Object]
[2018-02-15 15:30:59:0226] [info] DSX updates not available...
[2018-02-15 15:30:59:0227] [info] util: emit update-not-available for image
[2018-02-15 15:30:59:0227] [info] controller: emit update-not-available
[2018-02-15 15:30:59:0615] [info] Calling check for updates...
[2018-02-15 15:30:59:0615] [info] Checking for app updates...
[2018-02-15 15:30:59:0618] [info] Checking for image updates...
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you clean your environment and try a fresh install? To do that delete the following images if you have them:
`dsx-desktop:v1, hybridcloudibm/dsx-dev-desktop-dsx-core:latest, hybridcloudibm/dsx-dev-desktop-rstudio:latest, hybridcloudibm/dsx-dev-desktop-zeppelin:latest, hybridcloudibm/dsx-dev-desktop-jupyter:ana27spark, hybridcloudibm/dsx-dev-desktop-jupyter:ana27nonspark, hybridcloudibm/dsx-dev-desktop-jupyter:ana35nonspark` .

The syntax to delete the image (for ex: dsx-desktop:v1) is:
`docker rmi dsx-desktop:v1`

If you have a dsx-desktop container delete it using:
`docker rm -f dsx-desktop`

Finally remove the Settings file:
`del %APPDATA%\ibm-dsx-desktop\Settings`

Retry the install of the app and post the complete log if the install fails.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the DSX Desktop team. Sorry about the issue.

Unfortunately, nothing jumps out from the logs you included. I recommend installing the latest version, which has a significantly improved installer.

You can find the latest version here: https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/data-science-experience/purchase#purchasing.

Hope this helps.